# Get entries of one table based on another table in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables ,

moods and votes,

votes contains votes for each mood added using parameter vote.moodId

I am trying to get specific types of moods added on which i have voted. I am using cake php

```
$conditions = array(
                'Mood.userId'=>$userId,
                                'Mood.moodType'=>MOOD_IT
                );

            $moods = $this->Mood->find('all', array('conditions'=>$conditions,
            'fields' => $this->mood_fields_it,
            'order' => array('Mood.created DESC'),
                        'limit' => 20,
                        'offset' => $offset * 20
            ));
```

For now this is getting all moods added in database using my userId, instead how can i get the moods on which i have voted not that have userId = myUserid?

Comment: not familiar with cakephp, but it sounds like you need to do `JOIN` your `votes` table to your `moods` table and check if your vote `IS NULL`.

Comment: @Sean can u try simple mysql query , i will try to convert to cakephp version

Comment: Do you have associations set up in `Mood` and `Vote` model?

Comment: Just a guess as I don't know your `Mood` and `Vote` columns, and how they relate in respects to your vote - `SELECT ... FROM Mood LEFT JOIN Vote ON Mood.id = Vote.moodId AND Vote.userID = $userId WHERE Mood.userId = $userId ...` **OR** `SELECT ... FROM Mood LEFT JOIN Vote ON Mood.id = Vote.moodId WHERE Vote.moodId IS NOT NULL AND Mood.userId = $userId ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mood.php model should have

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Vote' => array(
        'className' => 'Vote',
        'foreignKey' => 'mood_id'
    )
);
```

In your votes table make sure you add a column **mood_id** (integer).
This binds the Votes to the Moods.
To filter based on related models you can use Containable. Add the following to  your AppModel.php:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then your find should look like this:

```
$conditions = array(
                'Mood.userId !='=>$userId, // all Moods that not yours
                 'Mood.moodType'=>MOOD_IT
              );

$moods = $this->Mood->find('all', 
                            array(
                                'conditions'=>$conditions,
                                'contain' => array('Vote' => array(
                                                              'conditions'  =>  array('Vote.userId' =>  $userId) // find your votes
                                                             )
                                                    ),
                                'fields' => $this->mood_fields_it,
                                'order' => array('Mood.created DESC'),
                                'limit' => 20,
                                'offset' => $offset * 20
                            ));
```